# Performance cost of table inheritance in a database

Tags: php, performance, inheritance, join, database-design

I'm currently trying to find a good method to create my future web sites, and I'm wondering : would making inheritance with tables in a database (mainly but not only with MySQL) have a non negligible extra performance cost ?

My idea was to separate the common stuff from the web site specific stuff.
For example, let's consider a user table.
The common stuff could be :

```
User :
- Id
- Login
- Password
```

and the specfific stuff could be :

```
Member :
- Id references User.Id
- Name
- Surname
- Email
- Age
- Sex
```

Could also work for pictures :

```
Image :
- Id
- Alt
- Title
- Src
```

Wallpaper :

```
- Id references Image.Id
- DominantColor
- Author
- Uploader
```

My goal is to have a reusable "core" for each of my websites, and making my tables this way would probably be a part of this work.

Also I'm extremely concerned about performance as I want my websites to be very optimized. So how big would be the cost of the extra joins?

Comment: The cost would likely be negligible so long as the joins are indexed and have easy to compare datatypes (integers).  Of course without knowing the number of joins, this is pure speculation.

Comment: Well most of the time i suppose there will be one join, in some cases two joins, and in some rare cases three joins. Also i always use unsigned integers as primary keys.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it then.  My concern would be more of the fact that if there isn't other "user" types (Members vs Admins lets say), that there's no purpose to inheritance.

Comment: Well users was maybe not a good example. But for say 3 different web sites, i could have 3 tables extending User table. Each time i would only have to do the work related to the extending table as the work related to the extended one would be already done and reused in each web site. The goal isn't to save disk space here by putting in a base table the common parts of 2 or 3 other tables, but to reuse this base from a site to another.

Comment: Unless you sometimes select from the `User` table directly without doing a join, I don't see how it will save you development effort.

Comment: Well i have not thought about everything yet, but i had to know if there would be a noticeable impact on performances. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for real is to benchmark. Normally it won't be a problem but if you have many joins on very large tables, you'll see the performance go down.

I can hardly see how this structure will save you development time and can only see that it will add complexity and thus will cost you extra time on development and debugging.